# Audit Login and Logout

Tags: sql-server

Good morning, please, has anyone used logins audit without using the Profile?

My client needs an audit that displays the logins that connected to the bank and after they disconnected.

In the case the profiler believe it is too heavy to keep active all the time collecting.

Do you have anything that might help us in this case?

thank you
Carol Lavecchia

Comment: Are they actual separate logins according to SQL Server, or are they using an application-based login system but the application itself always connects as a single login? I can't imagine every bank customer has a SQL principal...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a perfect use case for [Login Auditing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/configure-login-auditing-sql-server-management-studio). This will require a restart of the SQL Server.

Then, I would use [xp_readerrorlog](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1476/reading-the-sql-server-log-files-using-tsql/) to view the results. Something like:

```
xp_readerrorlog, @p1 = 1, @p3 = 'Login'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the use of [SQL Server Audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine).

Answer (score 0):

You can check the configure the SQL server security to log the sucessuful login (right-click on the server / Property / Security / click on the log option you want).

You will then be able to track the user that log on the instance by looking at the SQL server Log (xp_readerrorlog, @p1 = 1, @p3 = 'Login')

For the disconnection, you can create a server audit with the "logout_group" as the audit action type.

You can make the audit log in the application log or in a file.

Hope that helps.